# How to use gettext with Twig templates in Slim Framework?

Tags: internationalization, twig, translation, slim

I'm working with Slim 4 Framework with a Twig engine for templates.

Some time ago, Twig had an extension with `{% trans %}` tokens and `|trans` filter directly linked to gettext function.

Now things seems to be more complicated, Twig is linked to a Symfony Translator... do you know how can I link Twig to gettext?

I tried to create a custom filter, and it works, but I don't know how to create a tokenparser just to call gettext() function.

Answer (score 2):

The "official" way would be to use the [Twig-Bridge](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge) component that provides a Twig 3 `TranslationExtension`  to translate messages with the [trans](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#trans)
filter. For this, you have to install the [Symfony translator](https://github.com/symfony/translation) component.

The `TranslationExtension` can be configured with a custom `Translator` that must implement the `TranslatorInterface`. The Symfony Translator is able to use mo files as source. So you don't have to use the `gettext` extension anymore.

```php
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\TranslationExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Formatter\MessageFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\IdentityTranslator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\MoFileLoader;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
// ...

$twig = Twig::create($paths, $options);

$translator = new Translator(
    'en_US',
    new MessageFormatter(new IdentityTranslator())
);

$translator->addLoader('mo', new MoFileLoader());
$twig->addExtension(new TranslationExtension($translator));
```

If you still want to use the `gettext` function, you could also try to create a custom Twig function:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

```php
use Twig\TwigFunction;

$environment = $twig->getEnvironment();

$environment->addFunction(new TwigFunction('__', function ($message) {
    return __($message);
}));
```

Usage

{{ __('Hello world') }}

The downside of the second approach is that you need a custom text parser.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. The filter works for `|trans` but not for `{% trans %}`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved adding this dependency to composer:

`twig/extensions`

And this extension to Twig config:

```
 $twig = Twig::create($twigSettings['path'], $twigSettings['settings']);
 $twig->addExtension(new I18nExtension());
```

Comment: This extension is deprecated.